# Switching fonts in a document (Fira Sans and Charter)

Tags: fonts, small-caps

I am building my resume. I want the body text to be charter, and the headings to be small caps Fira Sans. How would I do this? Below is my MWE.

EDIT: To clarify, I am not using \section{}, \subsection{}, etc. Basically, I just want to change the body text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}

\usepackage[scaled=0.96,osf,sups]{XCharter}

\begin{document}
Here is a heading in Fira Sans small caps

Here is the body text in Charter font.



\end{document}
```

Comment: Typeset headings in Sans Serif.  The `scrartcl` documentclass does this by default.

Comment: I'm not using "\section{}", etc., sorry I wasn't clear on that

Comment: `\textsf{...}`  You really should read an introductory text on LaTeX if you didn't know this.

Comment: You should really reconsider using the sectioning commands and redefining those to your liking. And also take to heart Henri's recommendation. TeX is really powerful and not using it's capabilities is pretty much an unfortunate waste of resources. I'm not saying you shouldn't use it, but rather that you should learn how to use it and how to bend it to your will. In the process, you might learn one or two useful things about good typography ;)

Answer (score 2):

With `pdflatex`, you should not pass the `sfdefault` option. I added a shorthand for Fira Sans small caps for convenience.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[scaled=0.96,osf,sups]{XCharter}
\usepackage{FiraSans}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsfsc}{\sffamily\scshape}

\begin{document}

\textsfsc{Here is a heading in Fira Sans small caps}

Here is the body text in Charter font.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you care to comment on your code? I'm especially interested in your choice of options in the XCharter line. -- EDIT: No nead. I read the documentation like a big person.

Comment: @thymaro I just copied the OP's options.

Comment: A marvelous approach, indeed

Answer (score 0):

**This only works with Xelatex and Lualatex.**

If you want to use different fonts in your document then you can use `fontspec` package. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\fira}{Fira Sans}

% I don't have Charter font
\setmainfont{Roboto}

\newcommand\scheading[1]{\textsc{\fira{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \scheading{Here is a heading in Fira Sans Small Caps.}

    Here is the body text in Roboto font because I don't have Charter.
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: font]

Comment: You should note that the OP probably uses pdflatex (uses packages). Maybe you should note that this requires different engines.

Comment: Yes. Thanks TeXnician. I overlooked it. I will edit my answer to add this information.